# Special shuffling of the array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, shuffle

I want to shuffle my numpy array `a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 1]` in this way: `a = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`. So that the same elements do not stand side by side if possible. I know about `numpy.array.shuffle` but it generates all possible permutations uniformly. Therefore, with the same probability, can appear `a = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` or `a = [2, 2, 2, 1, 1]`. Is there vectorised solution for more difficult arrays? For example, for this `b = np.hstack([np.ones(101), np.ones(50) * 2, np.ones(20) * 3])` array.

Comment: What happens when you have 100 `1s`, 50 `2s` and 20 `3s`?

Comment: What you describe is not a shuffle, but a weaving of sorts. And maybe if there are more than one acceptable solutions, to pick one at random. The question is what exactly are you trying to do? Your last example is also impossible due to pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @ Jonas Palačionis: it is more difficult example of an array where can be several mixings which satisfy my condition.

Comment: @Reti43: Do you know about StratifiedKFold? I want to realise split method from this class. Without using sklearn. It can stratify based on the y labels. So I need to get the best sparse sort possible.

Comment: You need to put that information to the question. You're looking more for a sort than a shuffle. Have you looked at the source code of StratifiedKFold to see how it's done?